# I am trying to increment variable when the video reaches a cue point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, flowplayer

I am using flow-player and when my video reaches a certain cue point i am triggering  alert which has value of `i` variable :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    flowplayer(function (api, root) {
      api.bind("cuepoint", function () {
        api.pause();
        var i = 0 ;
        $(".quiz").slideDown(2000);
        $("."+i).fadeIn(2000);
        do {
            i++;
            alert(i);
            }
        while (i < 3);
        $('.done').click(function () {
        api.play();
        $(".quiz").slideUp(2000);
    });
      });
    });
</script>
```

now i want every time the video reaches the cue point the value of i at first pause should be 1 then at second pause should be 2 and so on...

Right now the value of i = 1 all the time in all of the alerts when the video hits the cue point !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring `i` outside of the function like below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    flowplayer(function (api, root) {
      var i = 0 ;
      api.bind("cuepoint", function () {
        api.pause();

        $(".quiz").slideDown(2000);
        $("."+i).fadeIn(2000);
        do {
            i++;
            alert(i);
             break;
            }
        while (i < 4);
        $('.done').click(function () {
        api.play();
        $(".quiz").slideUp(2000);
    });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Note:- you are re-initializing `i` again-and-again and that's why 1 always coming as output

Answer (score 1):

I figured out i was not breaking out of the loop and yes as Anant told i needed to initialise i before the flowplayer binder, here is the working code :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    flowplayer(function (api, root) {
        var i = 0 ;
      api.bind("cuepoint", function () {
        api.pause();

        $(".quiz").slideDown(2000);
        do {
            i++;
            alert(i);
            break;
            }
        while (i < 4);
        $('.done').click(function () {
        api.play();
        $(".quiz").slideUp(2000);
    });
      });
    });
</script>
```